# WebAPI ActionName not routing after publish: 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

When testing my action in VS, everything is working fine.

After deploying, /site/controller responds as expected (403) while /site/controller/action responds with a 404.

Other api projects deployed from the same solution to the same root are working as expected.

Each project is configured as an application in IIS.

Can you give me a clue on how to proceed or what information to add here that would clarify the configuration?

Global.asax:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;


namespace ssa
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(
            new QueryStringMapping("type", "json", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")));

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(
            new QueryStringMapping("type", "xml", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml")));
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ssa
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Iam not sure if you need to register all routes in your global.asax, but check this:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Check is your server configured to run targeted .net version it may be some differences between web api 1.0 and 2.0 at the server point of view.